# "The specified network name is no longer available" exception while reading file over the network

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, filestream, resume-download

I am using the below code using retry pattern to copy files over the network.

```
private int ReadSourceStream(FileStream _sourceStream, Byte[] _buffer)
{
    return _sourceStream.Read(_buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
}
```

In case the network is disconnected and exception is thrown, the `ReadSourceStream` is recalled with the same parameters until the network is resumed. The issue is that even after the network is resumed I still get the following exception

```
The specified network name is no longer available
```

I added `File.Exist` check before `_sourceStream.Read` and it returns true after network is resumed but while reading the stream it throws the exception.

Any of your help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you start with a clean fresh `FileStream` ? or did you pass the original (now broken) stream in?